# How can I hide div based on checkbox value in page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following checkbox in my view how can I hide div when checkbox is not checked on Page Load

```
<input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox" id="chkInvoiceStatusActive" asp-for="InvoiceStatus" value="true" />
<input type="hidden" class="k-checkbox" id="chkInvoiceStatusActive" asp-for="InvoiceStatus" value="false" />
<label>Invoice Status</label>
```

I tried the following but doesn't work,

```
 if ($('#chkInvoiceStatusActive').is(':checked')) {
            $("#invoiceDetails").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#invoiceDetails").hide();
        }
```

On click event its working great but I would like to check the value of the checkbox on page load and hide/show `invoiceDetails` div. Hide `invoiceDetails` if unchecked otherwise show `invoiceDetails`

```
 $('#chkInvoiceStatusActive').click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#invoiceDetails").show();
        } else {
            $("#invoiceDetails").hide();
        }
```

Comment: HTML IDs must be Unique! For the initial load, I would suggest using CSS. Once loaded, you can then bind callbacks to events like `click` or `change`.

Comment: Now that I review this further, it is not clear why you are hiding one or the other. I would remove the second element and either change the `value` or use it's already binary status. `if($(this).is(':checked'))` It will either be checked `true` or not checked `false`.

Comment: `$("#invoiceDetails").toggle($('#chkInvoiceStatusActive').is(':checked'))` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```js
const checkbox = document.querySelector("#checkbox"); //get checkbox
const div = document.querySelector("#div"); //get div
if(!checkbox.checked){  //if checkbox not checked
  div.style.display = "none"; //hide div
};
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<label for="checkbox">Checkbox</label>
<div id="div">Some interesting text here in the div.</div>
```

Note: this will only hide div on page load, if you want it on click this will help:

```
checkbox.oninput = () => {
  if(!checkbox.checked){  //if checkbox not checked
    div.style.display = "none"; //hide div
  } else {
    div.style.display = "initial"; //show div
  };
}
```

Note 2: if you want it reversed just delete the `!` from if

Answer (score 0):

Consider hiding all the elements with a class up front. Then reveal them as needed.

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(i, el) {
    var chk = $(el);
    if (chk.is(":checked")) {
      $("#" + chk.data("rel")).removeClass("hidden");
    }
  });

  $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#" + $(this).data("rel")).removeClass("hidden");
    } else {
      $("#" + $(this).data("rel")).addClass("hidden");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.invoice.status {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox" id="chkInvoiceStatusActive" asp-for="InvoiceStatus" data-rel="invoiceDetails" />
<label>Invoice Status</label>
<div id="invoiceDetails" class="invoice status hidden">
  Invoice Status: Good
</div>
```

I added an attribute to help identify the relationship fro mthe checkbox to the HTML elements.

When the page loads initially, all the items will be hidden. Then the JavaScript / jQuery will load and this will review the status of each of the checkboxes. If they are checked, it will remove the class, revealing the hidden element.

If the User then makes a change to one of the checkboxes, the `data-rel` attribute helps reveal the proper element.